# Asterisk library libgami

Tags: c, asterisk, glib, amazon-ami

I am trying to use libgami in order to retrieve differentes events from Asterisk AMI. However I do not know how to parse the response that is return with this library. As the code coments say:

> Returns: #GSList of status information (stored as #GHashTable) on
>   success,            %NULL on failure

How can I get the peers out of that list? Has anyone dealt with this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read this

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/asterisk+manager+events

to see how it looks.

After that just got hash element with name as described accordinly to your event.